# Draw two or three balls from an urn with ten balls

Tags: probability

My urn contains two black balls and eight white balls. What is the probability that I get the two black balls

a) after two draws
b) after three draws?

My approach is to draw a decision tree.

```
draw 1:        W              B 

draw 2:   W       B       W       B
draw 3: W   B   W   B   W   B   W   -
```

With two draws, the chance to get the black ball in the first draw is 2/10. Now I have 8 white balls and 1 black ball left, therefore the chance to draw the second black ball is 1/9.

Solution for a): 
$$\frac{2}{10} * \frac{1}{9}$$

With three draws, I have two more way of obtaining two black balls (W B B and B W B), therefore solution for b): $$\frac{2}{10} * \frac{1}{9} + \frac{8}{10} * \frac{2}{9} * \frac{1}{8} + \frac{2}{10} * \frac{8}{9} * \frac{1}{8}$$.

Are these solutions correct? (Sorry for the awkward method).

Comment: There is some intepretation needed. If it had said: "What is the probability that after $3$ draws, I have both black balls," everything would be clear, and your answer would be right. As it is, there is some doubt, since "after $3$ draws" could be interpreted as excluding getting them on the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct.

Note that each of the terms in your second answer can be written, after re-arranging, as:

$$\frac{8\cdot 2\cdot 1}{10\cdot 9\cdot 8}$$

So the total answer there can be written as:

$$\frac{3\cdot 8\cdot 2\cdot 1}{10\cdot 9\cdot 8}$$